# Mongodb check if value is in a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have a collection in my database that contains a field which is composed of 3 arrays, like this :

```
use_homepage: {
    home: [Array],
    hidden: [Array],
    archive: [Array]
}
```

This field represents the homepage of a user.

Each array contains an ObjectID that identifies projects shown on the user homepage.

I would like to check if my project id is in `use_homepage.home` or `use_homepage.hidden`, and if it is, remove the id from the array that match.

Can I do this with 1 (or 2 max) requests or do I have to make a request each time I have to check in another array ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you expect to update **one document at most**, you can try this:

```
db.entities.findAndModify({
    query: { $or : [
        { home: ObjectId('<HERE YOUR ID TO BE FOUND>') }, 
        { hidden: ObjectId('<HERE YOUR ID TO BE FOUND>') } 
    ]},
    update: { $pull: { 
        home: ObjectId('<HERE YOUR ID TO BE DELETED>'), 
        hidden: ObjectId('<HERE YOUR ID TO BE DELETED>') 
        } 
    }
});
```

As you can see, in general, you can search for some value and delete some other value.

The statement returns the original matching document (i.e. before the deletion is performed). If you want the modified document you can add the following attribute:

```
new: true
```

In case you search for many documents to update, this solution does not work, since `findAndModify()` works just on the first document matching the `query` condition.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in my case, it has to check all documents in the collection and pull the id from each document that have this id.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, i used to make 2 requests to do the job :

```
db.User.find({"use_homepage.home": id}, {_id: 1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    // If some users have the id in the array home
    db.User.updateMany({_id: {$in: users_match_ids}}, {
        $pull: {"use_homepage.home": id}
    }
});
// Do the same with 'hidden' array
```

If anyone see this post and have a better solution, I take it :)